# Saving information from URL to MySQL database

Tags: python, mysql

I basically have this url that has a bunch of information that I want to save into a database in MySQL using python.  I would post my code to show where I am but to be honest I really do not know where to start on how to save it to a database table.  Please let me know if this is confusing and I will try my best to clear it up.

Thanks

Comment: I think that your question is too broad and might get closed. I think you should be more specific. Try to google for `python mysql example`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this example from http://zetcode.com/databases/mysqlpythontutorial/. Of course you should first install a MySQL DB and MySQLdb library.

```
import MySQLdb as mdb
import sys

con = mdb.connect('localhost', 'testuser', 'test623', 'testdb');

with con:

    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS \
        Writers(Id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, Name VARCHAR(25))")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO Writers(Name) VALUES('Jack London')")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO Writers(Name) VALUES('Honore de Balzac')")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO Writers(Name) VALUES('Lion Feuchtwanger')")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO Writers(Name) VALUES('Emile Zola')")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO Writers(Name) VALUES('Truman Capote')")
```

To load html file from a url you can use [urllib2](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html):

```
import urllib2
f = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.python.org/')
html = f.read()
```

To parse the html and extract data you can use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
for a in soup.find_all('a'):
    # add to mysql
```

Comment: `with con as cur:` should already give the needed cursor...

Comment: I did see that example also but I was more so looking for a way to get that information from the URL I have and save that into a database

Comment: So - your problem is not related to MySQL at all just to parsing url's?

Comment: Well yes and no.  I have a URL that has a bunch of text.  I am trying to store that into a MySQL database table.  I am sorry if this sounds confusing, I can be pretty bad at explaining things.

Comment: So you want to parse html... I'll update my answer

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to help, that is what I am looking for